# I'm trying to installing react app using this command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

`npm install -g create-react-app`

Then I got Error like this:

`npm ERR! code EPERM`

`npm ERR! syscall mkdir`

`npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\node_modules`

`npm ERR! errno -4048`

`npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\node_modules'`

`npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\node_modules'] {`

`npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\system32\node_modules'] {`

`npm ERR!     errno: -4048,`

`npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',`

`npm ERR!     syscall: 'mkdir',`

`npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\node_modules'`

`npm ERR!   },`

`npm ERR!   errno: -4048,`

`npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',`

`npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',`

`npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\node_modules',`

`npm ERR!   parent: 'create-react-app'`

`npm ERR! }`

`npm ERR!`

`npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.`

`npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),`

`npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.`

`npm ERR!`

`npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the`

`npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running`

`npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.`

`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lagnajeet Jena\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-30T06_59_34_073Z-debug.log`

Comment: -g is to install package globally. You don't want that here. Follow the docs of react js to install, npx create-react-app my-app
 And make sure you have permissions in your terminal or use sudo su

Comment: But this npx create-react-app my-app is also showing some errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your npm install is system wide, which means you'll have to run your cmd/terminal as admin/root in order to use the `-g` flag on npm install. You could also reinstall node.js/npm into your user directory instead.